# How to join Ubuntu machine to windows server domain

Tags: testing

I want to join Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop and a windows server 2008 domain. I have tried to google this problem. I wasn't able to get likewise to work. I want to use Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop PC to join a windows server 2008 domain and be able to login with AD and map network drives from the window server.

Comment: Please check   [SSSD and Active Directory](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html)  as starting point.